# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting_

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Running this bit of code:

```
for row in csv_data:
    if skipHeader:
        skipHeader = False
        continue
    row = tuple(row)
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO july VALUES %r" % row, row)
```

And I get this error:

> TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I would appreciate any help, as I have been stuck on this for a while now

Comment: What is the second `row` for in the `cursor.execute()` call?